# why pandas explode method not working in my dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

here is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_path\\zzounds.csv')
df.head() 

      variation_type       main_image
  ['yellow', 'orange']   ['https://c1.zzounds.com/media/productmedia/fit,600by600/quality,85/GIGBAR_MOVE_ON_TRIPOD_812129-0eddea01276623f9a03cbfdd86eb3bd1.jpg', 'https://c1.zzounds.com/media/productmedia/fit,600by600/quality,85/GIGBAR_MOVE_ON_TRIPOD_812129-0eddea01276623f9a03cbfdd86eb3bd1.jpg']
```

I tried this code

```
df.explode(['variation_type','main_image'])
```

But it's returning the original dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are reading from csv file, you need to convert string list first

```py
df[['variation_type','main_image']] = df[['variation_type','main_image']].applymap(lambda x: pd.eval(x, local_dict={'nan': np.nan}))
# or
df[['variation_type','main_image']] = df[['variation_type','main_image']].applymap(lambda x: eval(x, {'nan': np.nan}))

df = df.explode(['variation_type','main_image'])
```

Comment: Ynjxsjmh getting this error `UndefinedVariableError: name 'nan' is not defined`

Comment: why I am getting this error ??? I also have few row those are empty or nan

Comment: can you please explain `.applymap(lambda x: pd.eval(x, local_dict={'nan': np.nan}` this part of code???

Comment: @hawaj `applymap` is to apply function to every value in dataframe and `pd.eval` is to evaluate Python expressions from a string-based or compiled-code-based.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its because python struggles to explode multiple columns in this manner.

You can use this code to get the results I believe you are expecting

```
data = {
    ' variation_type' : [['yellow', 'orange']],
    'main_image' : [['https://c1.zzounds.com/media/productmedia/fit,600by600/quality,85/GIGBAR_MOVE_ON_TRIPOD_812129-0eddea01276623f9a03cbfdd86eb3bd1.jpg', 'https://c1.zzounds.com/media/productmedia/fit,600by600/quality,85/GIGBAR_MOVE_ON_TRIPOD_812129-0eddea01276623f9a03cbfdd86eb3bd1.jpg']]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.apply(pd.Series.explode)
```

***Note: This will only work if all "list" fields are the same length

Answer (score 0):

Just to narrow down the issue, note that the dataframe displayed in your question does indeed work with `explode()`. If your values are strings that look like lists, then as suggested by @Ynjxsjmh, it may be necessary to convert them to list values first.

Sample test code:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
'variation_type':[['yellow', 'orange']],
'main_image':[['https://c1.zzounds.com/media/productmedia/fit,600by600/quality,85/GIGBAR_MOVE_ON_TRIPOD_812129-0eddea01276623f9a03cbfdd86eb3bd1.jpg', 'https://c1.zzounds.com/media/productmedia/fit,600by600/quality,85/GIGBAR_MOVE_ON_TRIPOD_812129-0eddea01276623f9a03cbfdd86eb3bd1.jpg']]})
print(df.to_string())

df = df.explode(['variation_type','main_image'])
print(df.to_string())
```

Input:

```
     variation_type                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  main_image
0  [yellow, orange]  [https://c1.zzounds.com/media/productmedia/fit,600by600/quality,85/GIGBAR_MOVE_ON_TRIPOD_812129-0eddea01276623f9a03cbfdd86eb3bd1.jpg, https://c1.zzounds.com/media/productmedia/fit,600by600/quality,85/GIGBAR_MOVE_ON_TRIPOD_812129-0eddea01276623f9a03cbfdd86eb3bd1.jpg]
```

Output:

```
  variation_type                                                                                                                           main_image
0         yellow  https://c1.zzounds.com/media/productmedia/fit,600by600/quality,85/GIGBAR_MOVE_ON_TRIPOD_812129-0eddea01276623f9a03cbfdd86eb3bd1.jpg
0         orange  https://c1.zzounds.com/media/productmedia/fit,600by600/quality,85/GIGBAR_MOVE_ON_TRIPOD_812129-0eddea01276623f9a03cbfdd86eb3bd1.jpg
```